# What does "It can be common or split between the digital and analog sections." mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

In [a technical data sheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7682_7689.pdf), I found the following paragraph:

> Use at least one ground plane.  **It can be common or split between the digital and analog sections.**  In the latter case, join the planes underneath the AD7682/AD7689.

What does the sentence in bold mean?  I find two possible meanings for this sentence, depending on whether "common" is affected by "between" or not:

- It can be common between both sections or split between them.
- It can be split between the two sections or it can be common.

Answer (score 1):

This is a usage found in more than printed circuit design, and "common" in this meaning is the antonym of "separate". In good design, the analog and digital circuits are confined to separate physical areas, typically one side or the other of a printed circuit design. The ground (in this case a ground plane), however, must connect them all together. This can be done in two ways. The first, simpler, way is just to use a layer of copper that covers the entire board. This depends upon layout to prevent digital function currents from straying into the analog section and causing noise. Because both functional areas have the copper layer "in common", it is called "common", and does not mean "usual" or "customary".

A more effective strategy is effectively to create two separate ground planes on the same physical layer. Each ground plane underlies only the functions it serves: digital or analog. The separate (not common) ground planes are only connected together at one or two points - in this case, the ground pins of the A/D converters being discussed.

Other examples of the useage are "to have common interests" (to have the same, or shared, interests) and "to unite to resist a common enemy" (the enemy threatens both parties, so both have the enemy "in common").

Answer (score 0):

It means the two sections can be together (common) or separate (split).

In the image below, the wires are common. If you remove the black casing they'd be split. 
[image: picture of multi-colored wires in a black casing]

Answer (score 0):

This can be hypothesized to be an instance of elision. According to this hypothesis, there is some original sentence which is condensed. Possibly, that sentence might be:

> It can be common, or **it can be** split between the digital **sections** and the analog sections.

Or it might be this one (which clarifies that there are exactly two sections: one digital and one analog):

> It can be common, or **it can be** split between the digital **section** and the analog section.

In either form, the second repetition of "it can be" (shown in bold) is omitted, and the two clauses are merged into one.

In the first form, the phrase "the digital sections and the analog sections" condenses by eliminating the repetition of the common noun "sections" (shown in bold). The *and* is then applied the section attributes: "digital and analog".

In the second form, the phrase "the digital section and the analog section" condenses by factoring out the repeated "section" noun, and pluralizing it to refer to both sections. The result is ambiguous: it no longer clearly spells out that there is a single analog section and single digital section.

It is remotely possible, even, that there are multiple sections which are not divided along digital and analog boundaries: each section has digital and analog domains, and "it" (the signal or whatever) is split between these. I.e. there is a section A, which is digital and analog, and a section B, also digital and analog. It is split between these two; i.e. between the digital-and-analog sections A and B.

For instance, if we take a phrase like "the black bird and the white bird" and merge it to "the black and white bird", we lose information. This could be referring to a single bird which has black feathers and white feathers. An article can help here: no such ambiguity is present in "the black and the white bird": since "the" occurs twice, there are two birds. (Illustrating how articles are important in English!)

Without seeing more of document, including any diagrams and whatever, it is impossible to be sure. The interpretation that there are two sections, of analog and digital kind, or two groups of such sections, is based on domain knowledge from electronic design, not on a pure interpretation of the words.